# What versions of nodejs support async Iterators

Tags: javascript, node.js

What versions of nodejs support async Iterators ? and is there a way to make it work in older version of nodejs.

syntax

```
for await (let content of promises) { // promises => array of promise objects
    console.log(content);
  }
```

Comment: Await for `Promise.all(promises)` then iterate

Comment: @Vivick yes but I want to use async Iterators

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi you can use `babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions` for older node. But I think babel V7 already comes with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V10 should support it. Here is an example with and without async iterator:

With:

```
async function print(readable){
   readable.setEncoding('utf8');
   let data = '';
   for await (const chunk of readable) {
     data += chunk;
   }
}

print(fs.createReadStream('./yourpath'))
```

Without:

```
function print(readable){
    readable.setEncoding('utf8');
    let data = '';
    readable.on('data', chunk => data += chunk)
    readable.on('end', () => console.log(data))
}

print(fs.createReadStream('./yourfilepath'))
```

And to use with older version of `nodeJS`, you can use `babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions`, but I do think babel V7 comes with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested async/await iterators with **8.9.1** successfully. For older versions await on all promises, then iterate on the result array.